# Function to Toggle all buttons with the same caption on a page in Access

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

On a Form in Access I have multiple Pages within a Tab, and multiple toggle buttons on each Page. Each togglebutton changes the status of different elements on the form. I have a 'master' genre toggle button which I want to use to toggle all of the buttons *within* that subgenre at the same time. There are 3 master buttons on each page that have the same Caption as the subgenre buttons, and all the subgenre buttons use the Tag 'Subgenre'.

So far I have a working code which will update all the controls which use that tag, but I want to use this code to be *called* from an OnClick event for each Master Genre (Season / Team etc), and just for the Page on which the Master button was clicked.

This updates all the subgenre buttons (for all genres) for the page specified:

```
Private Sub ToggleAllSubGenres()
        For Each Control In Me.pgeBatting.Controls
            If Control.Tag = "Subgenre" Then
        If tglSeason_BatALL.Value = True Then
            Control.Value = True
            Else
            Control.Value = False
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

But since the Master and Subgenre buttons all use the same Caption, I want the onclick event to update all the subgenre togglebuttons that have that same Caption and just *within that page*

```
Private Sub tglSeason_BatALL_Click()
Call ToggleAllSubGenres
End Sub

Private Sub tglTeam_BatALL_Click()
Call ToggleAllSubGenres
End Sub
```

etc

So when I click master button with Caption "S", it updates all togglebuttons within the page on which the Master button was clicked and which have the same caption as the togglebutton that was clicked, and have the tag "Subgenre", which will allow me to write one piece of code and have it apply to whichever Master genre was triggered, on whichever page it was triggered from.

Comment: So, what exactly are you asking? It seems you have a clear idea of what the buttons should do, what is the problem?

Comment: Hi @TomBrunberg I would like it to operate so that when I click master button with Caption "S", it updates all togglebuttons within the page on which that Master button was clicked and which have the same caption as the Master togglebutton that was clicked, and which have the tag "Subgenre". I would like one piece of code which can be called as an Onclick event from whichever Master togglebutton was triggered, on whichever page it was triggered from.

Comment: Still, what is your question? What is your problem in doing what you want? Or are you just asking somebody else to do your task?

Answer (score 0):

Key element required is Me.ActiveControl.Parent.Controls - allows the reference to whichever page on which the action is triggered.

```
Private Sub ToggleAllStats()
'Toggles all Stats toggles to the value of the Master toggle on whichever page it's triggered
        For Each Control In Me.ActiveControl.Parent.Controls
            If Control.Tag = "StatFilter" Then
                If Control.Caption = Me.ActiveControl.Caption Then
                    If Me.ActiveControl = True Then
                        Control.Value = True
                    Else
                        Control.Value = False
                    End If
                End If
            End If
    Next
End Sub
```